# make string optional and set default if nil in swift

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

I receive an object in a notification, one of whose properties is a string representing a file name.  If the string exists, I want to show one image.  If it does not exist, I want to show a default.

The following code shows an image if the string exists:

```
 if let contact = notification.userInfo?["contact"] as? Contacts,
            let pic = contact.pic  {
             if let img = self.loadImageNamed(pic) {
//Display the image
}
}
```

I am struggling, however, with syntax to detect missing string and show default image.

In the following variation, I tried using a coalesce operator but got an error
 that the pic is not an optional.

```
if let contact = notification.userInfo?["contact"] as? Contacts,
                let pic? = contact.pic ?? "default.pic"  {
                 if let img = self.loadImageNamed(pic) {
    //Display the image
}
}
```

Comment: How about using `else`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, `pic` is non-optional, it cannot be in an optional binding expression

```
if let contact = notification.userInfo?["contact"] as? Contacts {
   let pic = contact.pic ?? "default.pic"  
   if let img = self.loadImageNamed(pic) {
       //Display the image
   }
}
```

Comment: for some reason, after I accepted your answer, someone or group has downvoted this question and I've discovered gone through and downvoted a lot of my other questions.  Do you have any suggestions on what do when this happens?

Comment: No, I have no idea.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use optional chaining

```
let pic = (notification.userInfo?["contact"] as? Contacts)?.pic
let img = self.loadImageNamed(pic ?? "default.pic")
```

or, if `pic` can be an empty string:

```
let pic = (notification.userInfo?["contact"] as? Contacts)?.pic ?? ""
let img = self.loadImageNamed(!pic.isEmpty ? pic : "default.pic")
```